Reformatting a dataframe into wide format in R
I was wonder if there is a way for my DATA to be reformatted to my Desired_output below?
Specifically, for each unique study, we stick together a pair of pre and postNUMBER together, separately for t and c.
For example, for study == 2, we stick together a pair of pre and postNUMBER together going FROM:
study time   nt nc    mt    mc  sdt  sdc  outcome
2     pre    38 48  1.89  2.22 0.40 0.76  fram
2     post1  38 48  4.07  2.52 2.20 1.58  fram

TO:
study time            group  n    mpre     mpost  sdpre  sdpost outcome
2     pre-post1       t      38   1.89     4.07   0.40   2.20   fram
2     pre-post1       c      48   2.22     2.52   0.76   1.58   fram

ps. If a unique study in DATA, didn't have a pre (only consisted of postNUMBER) or postNUMBER (only consisted of pre), we simply leave it out.
DATA <- read.table(header=T, text="
study time   nt nc    mt    mc  sdt  sdc  outcome
1     pre    28 58  0.89  1.22 1.40 1.76  Conv
1     post1  28 58  5.07  3.52 3.20 2.58  Conv
1     post2  28 58  3.64  2.86 3.15 2.80  Conv
2     pre    38 48  1.89  2.22 0.40 0.76  fram
2     post1  38 48  4.07  2.52 2.20 1.58  fram
3     post1  31 18  2.07  1.52 1.20 0.58  voca
3     post2  32 18  3.07  2.32 1.12 9.85  voca
")

Desired_output <- read.table(header=T, text="
study time            group  n    mpre     mpost  sdpre  sdpost outcome
1     pre-post1       t      28   0.89     5.07   1.40   3.20   Conv
1     pre-post2       t      28   0.89     3.64   1.40   3.15   Conv
1     pre-post1       c      58   1.22     3.52   1.76   2.58   Conv
1     pre-post2       c      58   1.22     2.86   1.76   2.80   Conv
2     pre-post1       t      38   1.89     4.07   0.40   2.20   fram
2     pre-post1       c      48   2.22     2.52   0.76   1.58   fram
")


A tidyverse suggestion is to pivot_longer() in a first time,  to have one row per study-time-group (and a column for n , m and sd). In a second time, you can left_join the "post"  rows (filter(time!="pre") with "pre" rows  (filter(time=="pre"); with the appropriate argument.
I select some columns. Notice that I kept the row without pre with some NA ; they could be filtered if you want to leave them out.
library(tidyverse)

DATA <- read.table(header=T, text="
study time   nt nc    mt    mc  sdt  sdc  outcome
1     pre    28 58  0.89  1.22 1.40 1.76  Conv
1     post1  28 58  5.07  3.52 3.20 2.58  Conv
1     post2  28 58  3.64  2.86 3.15 2.80  Conv
2     pre    38 48  1.89  2.22 0.40 0.76  fram
2     post1  38 48  4.07  2.52 2.20 1.58  fram
3     post1  31 18  2.07  1.52 1.20 0.58  voca
3     post2  32 18  3.07  2.32 1.12 9.85  voca
")

data2 = 
  DATA %>%  pivot_longer(nt:sdc, 
                         names_to = c(".value","group"),
                         names_pattern = "(n|m|sd)(t|c)") 

left_join(data2 %>% filter(time !="pre"),
          data2 %>% filter(time =="pre"),
          by = c("study","group"),
          suffix= c("post","pre") ) %>% 
  select(study, time = timepost, group, npre, npost, mpre, mpost, sdpre,sdpost,
         outcome = outcomepost)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 10
#>    study time  group  npre npost  mpre mpost sdpre sdpost outcome
#>    <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  
#>  1     1 post1 t        28    28  0.89  5.07  1.4    3.2  Conv   
#>  2     1 post1 c        58    58  1.22  3.52  1.76   2.58 Conv   
#>  3     1 post2 t        28    28  0.89  3.64  1.4    3.15 Conv   
#>  4     1 post2 c        58    58  1.22  2.86  1.76   2.8  Conv   
#>  5     2 post1 t        38    38  1.89  4.07  0.4    2.2  fram   
#>  6     2 post1 c        48    48  2.22  2.52  0.76   1.58 fram   
#>  7     3 post1 t        NA    31 NA     2.07 NA      1.2  voca   
#>  8     3 post1 c        NA    18 NA     1.52 NA      0.58 voca   
#>  9     3 post2 t        NA    32 NA     3.07 NA      1.12 voca   
#> 10     3 post2 c        NA    18 NA     2.32 NA      9.85 voca

Created on 2024-05-07 with reprex v2.0.2

Using a join might potentially be more elegant, but here's an approach without it. Might give one some adjustability if needed.
Preparing DATA by filtering the studies without pre and adding groups to pre to enable assigning of pre and postX in case there are more postX.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

DATA_prep <- DATA %>% 
  filter(any(time == "pre"), .by = study) %>% 
  mutate(pgrp = if_else(time == "pre", 
                  max(as.numeric(str_extract(time, ".+(\\d+)$", 
                  group=1)), na.rm=T), 1),
         grp = time == "pre", .by = study) %>% 
  uncount(pgrp) %>% 
  mutate(time = if_else(time == "pre", paste0(time, cumsum(grp)), time), 
         grp = sub(".*(\\d+)$", "\\1", time), .by = c(study, grp))

summarizeing and unnesting the data by group association generated from variable names while in longer form.
library(rlang)

DATA_prep %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(study, time, outcome, grp)) %>% 
  mutate(group = sub(".*(.$)", "\\1", name), 
         name = sub("^(.*)[tc]$", "\\1", name)) %>% 
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  mutate(m = set_names(m, sub("\\d+", "", time)), 
         sd = set_names(sd, sub("\\d+", "", time))) %>% 
  summarize(time = paste(time, collapse="-"), 
            m = list(m), 
            sd = list(sd), 
            outcome = unique(outcome), .by = c(study, group, grp, n)) %>% 
  unnest_wider(c(m, sd), names_sep="") %>% 
  select(-grp)

output
  study group     n time        mpre mpost sdpre sdpost outcome
  <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  
1     1 t        28 pre1-post1  0.89  5.07  1.4    3.2  Conv   
2     1 c        58 pre1-post1  1.22  3.52  1.76   2.58 Conv   
3     1 t        28 pre2-post2  0.89  3.64  1.4    3.15 Conv   
4     1 c        58 pre2-post2  1.22  2.86  1.76   2.8  Conv   
5     2 t        38 pre1-post1  1.89  4.07  0.4    2.2  fram   
6     2 c        48 pre1-post1  2.22  2.52  0.76   1.58 fram

